# How to remove the Delimiter and insert the value into multiple rows

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a column called Menu in my table which as values like

```
ROW 1 : M20A-1|M20B-2|M20C-3

ROW 2 : M30A-3|M20C-4
```

I'm accepting the output to be as

```
Menu

M20A

M20B

M20C

M30A
```

first it should eliminate the `delimiter '|'` and ignore the value which is after '-' and get

I'm using this select statement to remove the delimiter '|' and insert the value  into

multiple rows :

```
SELECT  distinct 
      Split.a.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Menu
 FROM  (SELECT    
   CAST(left ('<M>' + REPLACE([MENU],'|', '</M><M>')+ '</M>' AS XML) 
AS String from 
  dbo.[Menusplit] ) AS A CROSS APPLY String.nodes ('/M') AS Split(a)
```

which as a function :

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Split_CSV] 
(@input VARCHAR(MAX)) 
RETURNS @Split TABLE(Columnslist VARCHAR(MAX)) 
AS 
BEGIN 
DECLARE        
@l_len INT, 
 @i INT=1, 
@N INT=1, 
 @csv_string VARCHAR(MAX), 
 @csv_strings VARCHAR(MAX)= @input + ',';   
 SET @l_len = LEN(@csv_strings) 
 WHILE @i<=@l_len 
 BEGIN 
IF SUBSTRING(@csv_strings,@i,1)=','      
 BEGIN 
 SET @csv_string = SUBSTRING(@csv_strings,@N,@i-@N)         
INSERT INTO @Split(Columnslist) 
SELECT  @csv_string
SET @N = @i+1; 
 END 
SET @i = @i+1; 
END 
RETURN ; 
END
```

but now how will i ignore the values which is after '-' and store the result into other table..

Comment: Show us what you have tried first.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT T2.Value FROM
(SELECT cast('<x>'+ Replace(MyStr,'|','</x><x>')+'</x>' As xml) As The_XML From Table1)T1 
 CROSS APPLY
(SELECT x.value('.','varchar(100)') As Value FROM The_XML.nodes('x') as f(x)) T2
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/64788/1)**

Output:

---

```
VALUE
M20A-1
M20B-2
M20C-3
M30A-3
M20C-4
```

If you  want to trim everything after certain character

Use `LEFT` combined with `CHARINDEX`:

```
SELECT LEFT(T2.Value, CHARINDEX('-', T2.Value) - 1) AS Value FROM
(SELECT cast('<x>'+ Replace(MyStr,'|','</x><x>')+'</x>' As xml) As The_XML From Table1)T1 
 CROSS APPLY
(SELECT x.value('.','varchar(100)') As Value FROM The_XML.nodes('x') as f(x)) T2
WHERE CHARINDEX('-', T2.Value) > 0
```

Note that the WHERE clause skips updating rows in which there is no semicolon.

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/64788/4)**

**Output:**

---

```
VALUE
M20A
M20B
M20C
M30A
M20C
```